# Log times when node process declined/too busy to respond new requests

Tags: node.js, webserver

We have a node Server running on Azure that does very little work for an App that is still under development. We're about to start marketing efforts and would like to host our website and landing page on this node Server.

We're not expecting millions of people visiting  our landing page/website. But we'd like to be prepared for 1000 page requests a minute during peak usage.

The Landing page has two images above the fold total size around 150KB.  Below the fold we have 5 Video files (400KB to 2MB range) that are lazy loaded and sent as files not streamed.

We plan to keep all these files in memory and serve from there to save on IO time.

Obviously we'll add more Servers if need to, But for now to start, Is there a way to log times when the node Server is too busy to respond to new connection/page requests ?

i.e. say at any point in time there are more incoming page requests that our Node Server can handle, how can we find out when that happened and how often that happens.

Comment: Have you considered serving your images and video objects as static? You could configure nginx to serve the files from the same vm where your node app runs. Or you could use a content delivery network. Avoid serving those files from your node app. You’ll overload it.

Comment: @Jones. Yes, I have considered it and plan to implement it too. It'll take some effort setting up reverse proxy and the environment the correct way as I have no experience doing it yet. I'm also considering CDN and will implement one or the other eventually. The question I asked while useful for me for my current short term need, it seems like a useful question for node Servers in general. Thus I posted it.